# Google Cloud is not serving my static files

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have deployed my laravel application, which is successfully running on my PC. But after deploying to gcloud I tried to access it and its failed to load all static assets created in the "public/" directory. I am getting 404 error for all the static files. Using Web Engine Source code view I checked the files and all the files are available in gcloud. Please let me know how can I serve my static files from gcloud.

Please find my app.yaml file.

```
runtime: php72

env_variables:
  ## Put production environment variables here.
  APP_KEY: My_Key
  APP_STORAGE: /tmp
  VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
  SESSION_DRIVER: cookie

  ## Set these environment variables according to your CloudSQL configuration.
  DB_DATABASE: mydb
  DB_USERNAME: myuser
  DB_PASSWORD: my_password
  DB_SOCKET: "/cloudsql/myproject:us-central1:myconn"


runtime_config:
 document_root: public
```

Comment: Consider hosting static website using Cloud Storage https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website

Comment: so there is no other way to serve public files?

Comment: When you say you deployed to gcloud, do you mean you're using App Engine? If so, is it standard or flexible and can you share the layout of your app.yaml?

Comment: @CorinneWhite added app.yaml content in the question

Answer (score 1):

There are two different AppEngine types that have different app.yam configuration:

1. **Flexible:** that uses [*document_root*](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/reference/app-yaml#the_runtime_config_section) configuration and app.php that point to your static content. 
   You can find [complete example of the app.yaml and app.php files on the github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/staticcontent). 
   There is ***env: flex*** to deploy app as the flexible environment. 
   So if you want to use flexible environment, your app.yaml could look like that:

```
runtime: php72
env: flex
env_variables:
               ...
               ...
runtime_config:
    document_root: public
```

2. **Standard:** that uses [*http_handlers* handlers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref). 
   Example to serve directory **as a static** resource:

```
runtime: php72
handlers: 
- url: /public
  static_dir: public
```

And another example, to serve content **from static** directory:

```
runtime: php72
handlers: 
- url: /
  static_dir: public
```

[More php app.yaml directory configuration handlers examples](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#example)

> Configuration directory is always relative to your app.yaml file location